# Getting issue in flutterwave live mode

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, flutterwave

I have implemented flutterwave test mode credentials and it is working fine in local but when I go for live and setup live key properly in my env file then also it is showing me error "Invalid public key passed". my flutterwave account is also in live mode.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```
RAVE_PUBLIC_KEY="FLWPUBK-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
RAVE_SECRET_KEY="FLWSECK-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
RAVE_SECRET_HASH="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: did you found any solution for this i am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the debug mode is false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is issue because you have used debug.
in your  `Flutterwave.forUIPayment`. Use this

```
isDebugMode: Foundation.kReleaseMode,
```